# Deep RL: Proximal policy optimization gradient calculation

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, loss-function, policy-gradients

Case:

Continuous action domain with 4 outputs (control problem) 
Policy and Value function approximation with fully connected neural networks

I understand that the loss function for PPO for the overall policy network is the clipped-loss function plus some stuff [Schulman, 2017].

> $L = E[L_{clip}(\theta) + c_1*L_{VF}(\theta) + c_2*S[\pi_{\theta}(s_t)]]$  `<1>`
>
> $g_{common} = E[\nabla_{\theta} log(\pi_{theta}(s|a)A]$

My questions are thus:

1. What is the gradient estimation of loss function `<1>` with respect to each predicted output? A common gradient estimation is shown above, but it is for a different objective function. The language in the paper is that `<1>` is a `surrogate objective` function.
2. How is loss/gradient calculated for non-output-level neural network weights given the clipped-loss function? Can the inner neurons use something like neg_log_policy with respect to target neuron output or mean-square-error or something else? I'm not sure because loss function `<1>` and similar use `Advantage function` and `reward`.